# jquery-mobile css styling disappears when editing html through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i am developing a my first jquery-mobile app, and im pretty new to both web development and java-script in general.

I have the following html in my content section:

```
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false"  data-content-theme="c">
            <h3>Results</h3>
            <p id="UnitResult"> Results..  </p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-content-theme="c" >
            <h3 id ="ShowAllh3">Show all</h3>
            <ul id="AllUnitsResult" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d"> 
              <li>list element</li>
              <li>list element 2</li> </ul>
        </div>
```

I also have a `<input type="number" .... onchange="calculate()>` and in the calculate function i do the following (amongst other):

```
$('#UnitResult').html(volume + " " + fromText + " equals " + result + " " + toText + ".");
$('#ShowAllh3').text('test');
for(var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
   $('#AllUnitsResult').append('<li class = "number">' + Units[i].name + ': ' + resultArray[i] + '</li>');
}
```

The problem i have is that the styling of these elements change when i add new html tags in realtime, is there any way to avoid this?

Before function is called:

[image: Before function is called:]

After function is called:

[image]

You can see that the new elements that are added to the list looks strange, and the heading that was "Show all", is changed to "test", but the formating is gone..

Comment: You should avoid inserting HTML with append and instead use DOM manipulation.

Comment: Start by creating an element like this `e = document.createElement(tagName);`, modify its properties and then append it to #AllUnitsResult like you did before.

Comment: I found the answer myself:

`$("#AllUnitsResult").listview("refresh");` does the trick :)

Comment: if you need a full page jQM refresh try .trigger('create');

Comment: where should i do that? i have two selects which are populated at $document.ready(), but if i have the acual page as the startpage they wont populate. if i however have an other page in the same document as the startpage, and then go to the page with the selects, they populate just fine. i assume is kind of the same problem?

Comment: .live( 'pagecreate',function(event) instead of (document).ready :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the list issue with:

```
$("#AllUnitsResult").listview("refresh");
```